# Plotly Dash children= clause

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm using dash in Python and have seen the "children= " clause. However in most cases I can remove it and the code runs just the same! Nowhere in the documentation I can find the reason for including it.

From the documentation you get:

```
The children property is special. By convention, it's always the first attribute which means that you can omit it:
```

So what's the purpose of children= in the code if you can decide to not use it and everything runs fine?

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible reasons someone might want to include it. From the Zen of Python:

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Another reason could be that you have a component with several different properties that you're assigning, and it fits the style better to have something like:

```py
html.Div(
    children='text',
    id='my-div',
    style=dict(color='green')
)
```

This could also help for syntax highlighting, which would then make the children match the coloring of the other properties. Otherwise, it might look different, and could become harder to see in a large block of code.

Using the kwarg also allows you to pass the `children` property as something other than the first attribute. I'm not sure there's any need to do that, but it is only possible with explicit assignment.

Comment: Also I sometimes like to put `children` as the last argument. This way you'll see important tags like `id` at the beginning. This is especially handy, when having many children.